# AutoCompleteBox WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone, restsharp, autocompletebox

I'm using AutocompleteBox control which gets data from REST service. My code looks like that:

MODEL:

```
public class Word()
{
   public int wordId {get;set}
   public int wordName {get;set;}
}
```

XAML:

```
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="AutoDictionaryTB" Populating="AutoDictionaryTB_Populating_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="63,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="383">
    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
    private void AutoDictionaryTB_Populating_1(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://XXX.XXXX.XX");
        var request = new RestRequest("/XXX.XXX.XX", Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("XX", "XX");
        request.AddParameter("XX", "XX");
        request.AddParameter("XXX", (sender as AutoCompleteBox).Text);

        var response2 = client.ExecuteAsync<List<Word>>(request, response =>
        {
            if (response != null && response.Data != null)
            {
                AutoDictionaryTB.ItemsSource = response.Data;
                AutoDictionaryTB.PopulateComplete();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unknow error occured. Check your Internet connection or try later.");
            }
        });
    }
```

IN THE LINE:

```
AutoDictionaryTB.ItemsSource = response.Data;
```

I have all walues I need so service is working perfectly. Why the control is not showing these walues? It's empty although **response.Data** is full of words.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ValueMemberBinding="{Binding wordName}" to the AutoCompleteBox to tell the component which property of the class it should use. If it doesn't work, add an ItemTemplate.